# Somewhere over the Atmosphere

Tags: riddle, haiku

> Destroyer of worlds
>   Nobody can escape me
>   Tragic death I am

What am I?

In an attempt to escape being "on hold", I will add this extra verse:

> Finite space I have
>   I'm infinitesimal
>   Infinite as well

Comment: i know, it's Noddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> A black hole

Because:

> Black holes suck in and crush planets / worlds, they do not allow any matter or even light to escape, and "black" is associated with death and tragedy

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Disease

Destroyer of worlds

> Diseases can be devastating to populations, especially when it first arrives where no one knows what it is or how to cure it

Nobody can escape me

> You can't *escape* disease but you can fight it and stop it.

Tragic death I am

> To die by being sick is unfortunately, very very tragic

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> an Atomic bomb?

Destroyer of worlds!

> yes!

Nobody can escape me

> almost anything will get destroyed!

Tragic death I am

> So true about atom bomb.

idea courtesy

> I got this idea from [J. Robert Oppenheimer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer) wiki page as he quote **from Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds**.